# permission denied to var/lib/dpkg

Tags: apt, sudo

Following error output on  `apt-get install -f`:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use root account or `sudo` when you want to change/install/fix packages with apt-get or apt or dpkg.

Answer (score 0):

As other people suggest your problem is that you do not have permission, to install something you have to use the `sudo` which will give you the root.